# unable to display correct answer when running programe input

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

When I run the programme, after I type start it says " car started..." WHICH IS CORRECT, HOWEVER, if i type start A SECOND time it says " Car is already started!
Car started...

When it should just says Car is already started! ONCE

Here is the programme codes thanks!

```
command = ""
started = False
while True:
    command = input("> ").lower()
    if command == "start":
        if started:
            print("Car is already started!")
        else:
            started = True
        print("Car started...")
    elif command == "stop":
        if not started:
            print("Car is already stopped!")
        else:
            started = False
            print("Car stopped.")
    elif command == "help":
        print("""
start - to start the car
stop - to stop the car
quit - to quit
        """)
    elif command == "quit":
        break
    else:
        print("Sorry I don't understand that")
```

WHEN RUN IS THE FOLLOWING:

```
start
Car started...
 start
Car is already started!
Car started...
```

I TRIED EVERYTHING AND HAVE HAD NO LUCK, IT WAS FROM A YOUTUBE VIDEO HIS WORKS MINE DOESNT

Comment: I think you want to indent `print("Car started...")` one more level, so it is part of the `else:` block.

Comment: You will have learnt that indentation does matter in Python :-)

Comment: sorry, could you give me an example of what would be correct? 
I dont see how it is already not indented

Comment: indent line 10 to the right four spaces so that it aligns with `started = True` and thus only executes when you are in the `else:` block.

Answer (score 0):

```
if command == "start":
    if started:
        print("Car is already started!")
    else:
        started = True
    print("Car started...")
```

In this block of code, the "Car started..." message is **not** indented as part of the inner if/else block.  So when `command == "start"` is true, that message is *always* printed.

You want that message to be indented one level deeper, so it is part of the inner `else` block:

```
if command == "start":
    if started:
        print("Car is already started!")
    else:
        started = True
        print("Car started...") # <-- indented further to the right
```